# Tailwind dark mode not work whith "important" settings

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

In Docusaurus not working Tailwind 3 dark mode if i set in
tailwind.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
      important: "#tailwind",
      content: ["./src/pages/**/*.{html,js}", "./src/components/**/*.{html,js}"],
      darkMode: ["class", '[data-theme="dark"]'], // or 'media' or 'class'
    ...}
```

in js

```
<div id="tailwind">
        <div className="bg-mainBackgroundColor dark:bg-blue-300 text-lg relative">
```

if i remove important: "#tailwind", dark mode starts working,how to make it work with id?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem myself today. The [data-theme="dark"] element will need to be a child of your "#tailwind". Looking at the build files noticed that the css had items like '#tailwind [data-theme="dark"] dark:text-gray-200'.

Whatever button or trigger you are using to toggle dark mode make sure its targeting a child of #tailwind.

```
<body id="tailwind">
  <div id="myapp" data-theme="dark">
    <div class="bg-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-700" />
    <button>Toggle Dark Mode</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    let btn = document.querySelector('button')
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let isDark = document.querySelector('#myapp')?.getAttribute('data-theme') === 'dark'

      if(isDark) document.querySelector('#myapp')?.removeAttribute('data-theme')
      else document.querySelector('#myapp')?.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.